# A question about the proof in functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces

I'm now reading Pazy's book about the semi-group operator. To prove the existence of the solution of KdV equation. He define the Hilbert space $H^s(\mathbb{R})$
$$
\Vert u\Vert_s=\left(\int(1+\xi)^s|\widehat{u}(\xi)|^2d\xi\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$
the inner product 
$$(u,v)_s=\int(1+\xi)^s\widehat{u}(\xi)\overline{\widehat{v}}(\xi)d\xi)$$
where $\widehat{u}$ is the Fourier Transform of $u$.
In  his book, I have the following question,when $s\geq 3$:

1.If $u\in H^s(R)$,why $Du\in H^{s-1}(\mathbb{R})$? ($Du$ denote $\frac{d}{dx}$)

2.Why $Du\in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$? And $ \Vert Du \Vert_{\infty}\leq C \Vert Du \Vert_{s-1}\leq C  \Vert u \Vert_s$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The norm should be defined as $\lVert u\rVert_s^2:=\int_{\mathbb R}(1+\xi^2)^s|\widehat u(\xi)|^2d\xi$.

1. We use the fact that $\widehat{Du}(\xi)=i\xi\widehat{u}(\xi)$. Then 
   \begin{align}
   \lVert Du\rVert_{s-1}^2&=\int_{\Bbb R}(1+|\xi|^2)^{s-1}|\xi|^2|\widehat u(\xi)|^2d\xi\\
   &\leq \int_{\Bbb R}(1+|\xi|^2)^{s}\widehat u(\xi)|^2d\xi\\
   &=\lVert u\rVert_s^2.
   \end{align}
2. We use the inversion formula for Fourier transform. 
   \begin{align}
   |Du(x)|&=C\left|\int_{\Bbb R}e^{itx}it\widehat u(t)dt\right|\\
   &\leq C\int_{\Bbb R}|\xi||\widehat u(\xi)|d\xi\\
   &=C\int_{\Bbb R}\sqrt{|\xi|}(1+\xi^2)^{-(s-1)/2}|\sqrt{|\xi|}\widehat u(\xi)|(1+\xi^2)^{(s-1)/2}d\xi\\
   &\leq C\sqrt{\int_{\Bbb R}\xi(1+\xi^2)^{-(s-1)}d\xi}\lVert Du\rVert_{s-1}
   \end{align}
   (the last integral is convergent as $2(s-1)-1>1$).

Comment: How can I prove $L^2(R)=H^0(R)$?That is to say is $|\widehat{u}(\xi)|^2=|u(\xi)|^2$?

Comment: It's a result about Fourier transform: we define it on $L^1\cap L^2$, show that it's an isometry and extend it to $L^2$.